# Зависает приложение на IOS при добавлении svg

Tags: html, css, ios, svg

После добавления svg на фон, приложение на IOS стало очень сильно зависть.

Код SVG :

```html
<svg width="375" height="682" viewBox="0 0 375 682" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g filter="url(#filter0_f_369_53)">
    <path d="M296 293.735C296 386.925 200.279 557 131.892 557C78.0447 557 -17 386.925 -17 293.735C-17 200.545 53.0674 125 139.5 125C225.933 125 296 200.545 296 293.735Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear_369_53)" fill-opacity="0.6"/>
  </g>
  <g filter="url(#filter1_f_369_53)">
    <path d="M371 327.939C371 420.639 357.794 488 317.201 488C276.608 488 224 420.639 224 327.939C224 235.239 247.814 135 288.407 135C329 135 361.149 187.344 371 327.939Z" fill="url(#paint1_linear_369_53)" fill-opacity="0.6"/>
  </g>
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter0_f_369_53" x="-142" y="0" width="100" height="682" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
      <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="62.5" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_369_53"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="filter1_f_369_53" x="99" y="10" width="397" height="603" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
      <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="62.5" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_369_53"/>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_369_53" x1="131.892" y1="125" x2="-43.3584" y2="237.15" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#0BA438"/>
      <stop offset="0.864583" stop-color="#EE9A4D"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="paint1_linear_369_53" x1="261.887" y1="135" x2="485.473" y2="314.534" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0.999391" stop-color="#4D69D4"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0BA438"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема в размере изображения и `<linearGradient>`, что бы решить данный вопрос, или удалите всё лишнее из SVG (его можно упростить) или сохраняйте это изображение в формате `webp`. Сталкивался с такой же проблемой, но когда фиксировал позиционирования картинки.